# How to handle memory management with an autoreleased NSString that is assigned to an IBOutlet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

When an autorelease string is assigned to an IBOutlet property, Is it getting retained. Like lets say I have an property

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *lblName;
```

Now in my `viewWillAppear` I assign `lblName` a string as:

```
lblName = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"NameString"];
```

So what is the retain count for this string, do I need to make sure I assign `lblName = nil;` before assining it a new string everytime view is being added or `viewWillAppear` is invoked.

Also another question is about `UIImageView`

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgView;
```

Now when I use animation as

```
NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//some images are added to imageArray

imgView.animationImages = imageArray //NSMutableArray of autoreleased images.

[imageArray release];
```

are the images in that array are retained or is this array is being retained, since `imgView` is having a retain property.

Answer (score 0):

When using properties with the `retain` attribute, you don't use the simple assignment.

You need to do the following:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *someString;
@synthesize someString;

-(void)someMethod
{
    // either this
    [self setSomeString:@"Oh hai!"];

    // or this
    self.someString = @"Oh hai!";

    // but never this
    someString = @"Oh hai!";
}
```

The first two versions call the method `setSomeString:` but the third one doesn't. It merely assigns the pointer of `@"Oh hai!"` to the instance variable `someString`. This is a problem because it won't call `[someString retain]` *but* when finished, it will call `release` and cause an exception to occur because you're releasing it more than it was retained (since it wasn't retained when you assigned it).

For more information on memory management in iPhone look at [this.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-BEHDEDDB)

By the way, the `IBOutlet` macro actually evaluates to an empty macro. It is merely used by Interface Builder to flag a property as usable in a NIB.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean: 
iblName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"NameString"];

stringWithFormat: Will return an autoreleased string, so the retain count starts at one, assigning it to the text property will increment it to too but, since it is autoreleased, it will go back to one the next time the run loop drains the autorelease pool.

When you set it, the label will release the string and retain the new one, so you should be fine.

In the second case, the array will retain the autoreleased images, and setting animationImages will retain the array.

Comment: Sorry I dint get you about the array release. Like Do I need to release the imageArray one more time, and do I need to relase the autoreleased images also.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I ran across it and would like to add some detail for anyone else that might do the same.

A good way to check the retain count of the objects you have allocated is to use the Instruments Application and run Object Allocations.  You can do this by going to the Product menu (Xcode 4.o) and select Profile.  This will start Instruments.  Choose Allocations as your trace template.  It is under the Memory category on the left.

If you aren't familiar with this I am sure you will start to find it very helpful. You can run this with your device or simulator.  After it all starts up, scroll down the list of object allocations.  You will find things like UIImage, UIImageView, UIScrollView and each of these objects will have a count of how many times it has been created and how many living objects are allocated.  Just use your app and keep an eye on the numbers.  You will be able to see if your objects are being dealloc or alloc as you test.

If you mouse over the object you are interested in, you will see a little side arrow button appear.  Click that to get some details on the malloc and free commands being sent to the object.  You can also see how much memory is malloc or free.  If you expand the details on the side of the screen, you can also see the stack.

So if you are unfamiliar with this tool, definitely check it out.  If you are having memory problems or questions about retains on your objects, this is the place to check it all out.

All the best - fxshot